# How does the control state work in UIControl?

Tags: ios, enums, uibutton, uicontrol, bitmask

I am working on a ios project which uses UIButton. I used `[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];` But I am not fully understand the mechanism. I know it's emun and  bitmask process. Can anyone explain a little bit more to me? thanks.

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A control can have [more than one states at a time](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW11) eg. selected and highlighted can co-exist, and so on.

So you can specify titles and images for combinations of states.

Eg.

```
UIButton * button;
//initialization code
NSString * title = @"Title";
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
title = [button titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
```

The bitmasks are used so as to produce unique value for each and every combination of values - try them using bitwise OR and you will get it. It is not very much unlike currency notes of $1,$2,$5,$10 etc that are capable of paying any integer amount e.g. $1 and $2 bills can be used to pay $3, $4 and so on, so you only need definite number of bills.

Comment: so, forState:UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected
means setting stuff for Highlighted and Selected. And the uniqueness of the state is the reason why they used bitmask, right?